Live-Action Fantasy Movie Based on Fairy Tales/Snow White?
I remember seeing this as a kid, probably 16 years ago or so, so it was likely late 90s early 2000s. I believe it was a made-for-tv movie, but am not certain so. It was live-action and based on Fairy Tales, especially Snow White. It followed closely to the Grimm version of the fairy tale. I specifically remember that the Evil Queen put the comb into Snow's hair and she fell asleep. I think the Queen used her own comb so that Snow would trust it, but it was poisoned. I think there was something about werewolves in it.

This sounds like The 10th Kingdom (2000). The 10th Kingdom is an American fairytale fantasy miniseries.

IMDB
Plot  Wikipedia

In a hidden realm, fairy tale characters inhabit nine magical kingdoms
  where an Evil Queen plots to rule them. She is trapped in the Fourth
  Kingdom Prison under the rule of Prince Wendell, the spoiled, arrogant
  grandson of Snow White. Weeks before his coronation ceremony, the
  Queen enlists the help of the brutal Troll King and his three children
  to release her before the Prince makes his annual visit to the prison.
Prince Wendell is captured by the Evil Queen, who is his wicked
  stepmother and turns him into a Golden Retriever while her very own
  Retriever is transformed into Wendell. In panic, the transformed
  Prince flees through the Prison and stumbles across a traveling mirror
  in the basement and is transported to New York City. The Troll King
  orders his bumbling children Burly, Blabberwort and Bluebell to bring
  back the escaped Prince while the Queen releases a half-wolf prisoner
  (who is simply called Wolf) to retrieve him instead.
Meanwhile, regular Manhattan inhabitants, headstrong waitress Virginia
  Lewis and her oafish father Tony encounter the mishaps caused by the
  new magical arrivals to the city; including Wolf falling helplessly in
  love with Virginia and Tony being given six wishes (which he foolishly
  uses for personal gain and have a tendency to backfire). With Virginia
  having already determined that the transformed Wendell- whom she calls
  'Prince' before learning his identity- is more than a standard dog,
  Tony uses his last wish to wish for the ability to understand the dog,
  who urges them to travel back to The Nine Kingdoms with him to break
  the spell. Tony, feeling responsible for Prince, reluctantly accepts
  and Virginia and Tony are taken back to the realm through the magic
  mirror.
At first, Tony and Virginia are desperate to get home with the magic
  mirror being taken from place to place around the Kingdoms, being
  cleared out of the prison, taken as a prize for a sheep-rearing
  contest, and then sold in an auction. The group travel the lands in
  pursuit of the mirror, facing many dangers and challenges in the
  process, including Virginia's hair being enchanted to an impossible
  length, the Queen's Huntsman, and a conspiracy by the descendants of
  Little Bo Peep to control a town's wishing well. During their journey,
  Wolf questions his loyalty to the Queen in order to gain favour with
  the stubborn Virginia and quickly sides with them. This act prompts
  the Queen to send her relentless and cold-blooded Huntsman to capture
  the Prince along with Virginia and Tony.
Virginia eventually meets the ghost of Snow White, who reveals she is
  destined to save the Nine Kingdoms. Tony also recognizes the Queen as
  his long lost wife and Virginia’s mother. They travel to the castle to
  stop her, but Wolf seems to have betrayed Tony and Virginia. They are
  thrown into the dungeons where Tony reveals to Virginia that her
  mother had been suffering a mental breakdown and had tried to drown
  Virginia the night she left. The Queen has her imposter Prince Wendell
  crowned king and then tries to poison all the monarchs who attend the
  ceremony.

Christine White (Evil Queen) Wikia

Luckily, Wolf switches the poison for a sleeping potion and everyone
  escapes unharmed. Virginia must kill the Evil Queen in self-defense,
  which pains her greatly, while Tony defeats the trolls. The real
  Prince Wendell turns back into a human and takes the throne, pardoning
  the trolls to return to their kingdom after the death of their father.
  Grateful to Tony for all his help, Prince Wendell offers him a job at
  the palace and Tony accepts. Virginia returns to New York City,
  accompanied by Wolf.
The Queen once more tried to strangle Virginia but was instead
  scratched by the poisoned hair comb Virginia had found in the Swamp
  Witch's tomb. Realizing that her death was now inevitable, the Queen
  turned and took a few steps before falling to the floor. In Virginia's
  arms, her sanity finally returned and she lamented her own actions,
  remembering who she was and that Virginia was her "little girl", whom
  she assured she did love. She acknowledged that it was too late for
  her saying "I gave away my soul" before dying.




